# How to send mail on specific date?

Tags: rules, datetime, emails

Hi I have a content containing one *date field*, it is an empty date field. I mean there is no current date value. when author clicks on that *date field* and he assigns one date that may be any date on future. What date he will give in future, on that date in future I have  to trigger a mail to him.